# how do i fix MIPS Program Parser Error in QTSPIM while loading a program

Tags: mips, spim

```
.data
s3:.word 3,5,7,5,0

.text

.globl main

main:
la $t3, s3      # load adress of s3 into $t3
li $t4, 5       # load x=5 in $t4
li $t5, 0       # load c=0 in $t5
li $t6, 0       # $t6 will be list index i starting with 0  

while:
add $t7, $t6, $t3   # get adress of s3[i]
lw $t8, 0($t7)      # load word from s3[i]
beq $t8, $t1, exit  # if s3[i] == 0 break

bne $t8, $t4, if    # if s3[i] != x jump to if:
addi $t5, $t5, 1    # increment counter
if:

addi $t6, $t6, 4    # increment list index
j while
exit:
```

When loading the program file into SPIM i get this Error https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EIsc.png
which states theres a parser error on line 2

Comment: Put spaces after the commas.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with QtSPIM 9.1.12 on Windows.